# PHP mkdir не создает папку с русским названием

Tags: php

Здравствуйте,

Появилась тут такая задача, бьюсь над нею уже более 2 дней. В общем, имеем команду `mkdir()` все с ней отлично, но при попытке создания папки, папка создается с иероглифами, допустим `Р›Р°Р»Р°` причем все кодировки utf-8. Что делать, как быть?

Comment: Использовать русские символы в именах - плохая идея. Вот, что нашёл http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33299404/mkdir-utf-8-file-name

Comment: Если имена папок достаточно короткие, то как вариант использовать md5($foldName) для "генерации" имени папки, но тогда по именам папок в "сыром" виде нереально будет понять что есть что.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте предварительно перевести передаваемую переменную с помощью функции `iconv()` из кодировки `UTF-8` в `CP1251`.